# Como saber qual activity está aberta, rodando?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Tenho duas activities, Activity1 e Activity2.

Preciso saber se a 2 está ativa ou não, nas duas activities.

Exemplo:

```
if (activityrunning == activity2){
   //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: mas esse codigo vai estar rodando em background como um service?

Comment: @NeuberOliveira pode ser em background, só num momento dentro do app preciso saber se é a 2 que está ativa.

Comment: ta meio dificil de entender o que precisa, mas por acaso é um fragment que esta nas duas activityes? E nesse fragment voce quer saber qual activity esta sendo executada?

Comment: @NeuberOliveira a resposta abaixo resolve o problema. Muito obrigado!! É um click que é aproveitado nas duas activities, mas se a 2, por exemplo estiver ativa, ele leva para outro lugar no codigo! Obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é criar uma variável estática e altera-la de acordo com o ciclo de vida da *activity*. Por exemplo, quando o método `onStart()` executar a variável recebe `true`. Caso a executar o `onStop()`, então a variável receberá o valor `false`. Veja abaixo:

```
class MinhaActivity extends Activity {
     static boolean status = false;

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         status = false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         status = true;
      } 
}
```

Como a variável é estática, você pode acessar sua variável de qualquer *activity*. Veja:

```
OutraActivity.status;
```